# mysql command to get data of 2 tables

Tags: mysql

I would like to get data from 2 mysql tables.

Table tbl_1:

[image]

Table tbl_2:

[image]

I tried this:

```
SELECT `tbl_2`.* 
FROM `tbl_1` 
    LEFT JOIN `tbl_2` ON `tbl_1`.invoiceID = `tbl_2`.invoiceID 
WHERE `tbl_1`.customerID = "463";
```

My result:

[image]

The results looks good but not perfect.
I get many null rows which are not be in my result.
only the first both rows should be in the result.

Where is my fault?

Comment: Just switch tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The LEFT JOIN keyword returns all records from the left table `tbl_1`, and the matching records from the right table `tbl_2`. So change the order of the tables

```
SELECT `tbl_2`.* 
FROM `tbl_2` 
    LEFT JOIN `tbl_1` ON `tbl_1`.invoiceID = `tbl_2`.invoiceID 
WHERE `tbl_1`.customerID = '463';
```

Answer (score 2):

The LEFT JOIN keyword returns all records from the left table (tbl_1), and the matching records from the right table (tbl_2).

Maybe you should try 'INNER JOIN' instead of 'LEFT JOIN'?

Answer (score 0):

Sir,

You have two tables (Table1 and Table2) and there is a COMMON column called `invoiceID` in both your tables. So if you want to select some columns from these two tables for a given CUSTOMERID:

```
SELECT Table1.*, Table2.*
FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2
ON Table1.invoiceID = Table2.invoiceID
WHERE Table1.CUSTOMERID = "463"
```

Comment: I would recomment LEFT JOIN for two tables

Comment: he doent want  any rows who has NULL columns, that's why I suggested INNER JOIN. otherwise you of course go with it depending on the result, which i guess OP is not very clear about.